# void (*var_name)(data_type) - How does this declaration work?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

How the above declaration of function pointers work in C/C++. I first encountered this declaration while making use of the signal.h file in c programming.

Comment: [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org/?q=void+%28*var_name%29%28data_type%29)

Comment: See the [Clockwise/Spiral Rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html).

Comment: [`signal()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/signal) is a wonderful and classic real life example used to teach how to read function declarations, specifically using pointers to functions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do function pointers in C work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It's listed under section Important notes that may save you time of tag info of tag C

Comment: This is how you declare a pointer to a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://cyan-lang.org/jose/courses/06-2/lc/Ponteiros-para-Funcoes.htm

It's in Portuguese, Example:

in C, we can declare a pointer to function with the syntax

```
void (* f) ();
```

In this case, f is a pointer to a function with no parameters and that returns void. F can point to a compatible function:

```
F = maximum;
```

Maximum is a function declared as

```
void max () {
    Puts ("Hi, I'm the max");
}
```

Maximum can be called from f using any of the syntax below.

```
(* F) (); / * Maximum call * /
F (); / * Maximum call * /
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer made me understand this better

Answer (score 2):

This is a function pointer decalaration

`void (*var_name)(int)`

In this example, `var_name` is a pointer to a function taking one argument, **integer**, and that returns **void**. It's as if you're declaring a function called "*var_name", which takes an int and returns void; now, if *var_name is a function, then var_name must be a pointer to a function